# AlwaysOn Availability Groups on Secondary Replica

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, configuration

We have a Primary Server A with a Database. It has AlwaysOn ReadOnly Asynchronous which moves data to Server B.

Out of curiosity, is it possible to place Server B on AlwaysOn and move it to another Server C Asychronous Read Only?

We want to reduce the workload/performance on our main server A OLTP; however, we want two replicas. We're just curious.

So AlwaysOn from

- Server A → ServerB → ServerC

---

**Additional details**

We want to make Database B as a primary replica on AG, which then passes to secondary Database C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Out of curiosity, it is possible to place Server B on AlwaysOn and move it to another Server C Asychronous Read Only.

If it's the same databases in the already existing Availability Group, then the only way you could theoretically do this is by re-architecting your solution so that Server B and C were in their own cluster and utilizing distributed availability groups from Server A.

I would not do this.